# How comes that the integral ( indefinite) of a function f is always a primitive of f , although the domain of the integral is not the same as f's.

Tags: calculus, integration, soft-question, indefinite-integrals

The first part of the Funfamental Theorem of Calculus says that any function defined as the integral of *f(t)dt* from some point *a* to *x* is a primitive of *f*.

Out of this, I conclude that the domain of the integral function is an interval limited by *a* from the left.

But the domain of function f need not be limited by *a*.

Hence my question: **isn't this at least surprising that the integral function, although its domain need not be identical to the domain of *f* is guaranteed to be a primitive of *f*?**

I can't give any solid reason why it seems surprising to me, but ***I would naturally tend to think that the primitive of a function *f* should have a domain at least as big as  its derivative ( namely, *f*) .***

My question may include a lot of false assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the fact that, if $b<a$, then $\int_a^bf(t)\,\mathrm dt=-\int_b^af(t)\,\mathrm dt$. Therefore, yes, the map $x\mapsto\int_a^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt$ *is* defined when $x<a$.

Comment: Is it correct to say that the indefinite integral is ( loosely speaking) the area function A such that (1) A(x) is the integral of f(t)dt from a to x when xis equal to a or x>a and (2) A (x) is the integral of f(t)dt from x to a when x< a. Would this be a correct way to construct a " big" indefinite integral including both cases, that is, including the whole domain of f?

Comment: Well, that “area” may be negative (in a region in which $f$ is negative). And you should add another $-$ sign when $x<a$. Other than that, you are right, yes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You may use that:

$$\int_a^b f(t)dt = - \int^a_b f(t)dt $$

Hence your function can be definied even for $x<a$, so you don't have a left bounded domain.

Answer (score 0):

Let $I$ be an intervall in $ \mathbb R$ and $f:I \to \mathbb R$ continuous. If $c \in I$ and if  $F: I \to \mathbb R$ is defined by

$$F(x):= \int_c^x f(t)dt,$$

then $F$ is an anti-derivative of $f$.